# Transaction management for memory changes in Standalone java application

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a standalone java application in which one function call from the GUI will result in multiple changes in instance variables of different classes.We want to write a transaction manager for this so that if some exception is thrown then changes done in memory prior to execution block are reverted.We can surely do it a naive way by creating a copy of instance variable before the call , and reverting the changes if exception occurs , but i am looking for some sophisticated and a good design to handle this problem.

Please let me know if any one has idea of some framework or generic design that can be used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Memento design pattern to store the state of the objects. If everything goes fine, you delete the last stored state. If there is some problem, you restore the last state. Here is a reference (a poor one) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern. Try Google for more details.

The Memento works similarly of what you said, but it formalizes an architecture to provide this feature.

Here is the classical reference: [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1342931128&sr=8-1&keywords=design+patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Answer (score 0):

Cloning (by cloning / serialization & deserialization or another mechanism) the object to a transactional view and propagating the state back to the (hidden) committed instance (combint with an optimistc locking mechanism based on version counters) is a common approach. (It is e.g. used by  https://github.com/JanWiemer/jacis transactional object store...)